# Metadata generation failure installing the TTS API by coqui.AI - python

Tags: python, docopt

Ever since i first tried downloading the API stated above, i kept getting this error:

```
Using cached docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [6 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\----\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jwyv85is\docopt_9a12a30d1bf5412288252a770efbade4\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
      from docopt import __version__
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am using Windows 11, on an Nvidia GTX 1060, and using the Spyder IDE (as my tutor uses it too and for simplicity) if that helps. Installer is pip

I was expecting no error. Since i was using pip, i thought it would be straigt forward

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.